# How to SUM the result of two different SQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, metabase

I want to SUM these two different queries. I joined both with USING function. but it shows the two results in two different cells.

I need a single result to SUM these two queries where the answer should be 4069.

The CODE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Active_Projects FROM
(SELECT ProjectID, ProjectStatusID, ClientID
FROM project) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ProjectStatusID, ClientID, ProjectStatusName
FROM ProjectStatus) b
ON (a.ProjectStatusID = b.ProjectStatusID AND a.ClientID = b.ClientID)
WHERE ProjectStatusName LIKE '%active%'
AND a.ClientID = 4

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Projects
FROM Project
WHERE ClientID=4
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSNH7.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVED.png)

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRkkr.png)

Comment: My Code

SELECT COUNT(*) Active_Projects FROM
(SELECT ProjectID, ProjectStatusID, ClientID
FROM project) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ProjectStatusID, ClientID, ProjectStatusName
FROM ProjectStatus) b
ON (a.ProjectStatusID = b.ProjectStatusID AND a.ClientID = b.ClientID)
WHERE ProjectStatusName LIKE '%active%'
AND a.ClientID = 4

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Projects
FROM Project
WHERE ClientID=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `select query1+ query2;`

```
select (
    SELECT COUNT(*) Active_Projects FROM
(SELECT ProjectID, ProjectStatusID, ClientID
FROM project) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ProjectStatusID, ClientID, ProjectStatusName
FROM ProjectStatus) b
ON (a.ProjectStatusID = b.ProjectStatusID AND a.ClientID = b.ClientID)
WHERE ProjectStatusName LIKE '%active%'
AND a.ClientID = 4
) + (
SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Projects
FROM Project
WHERE ClientID=4) ;
```

Comment: Could you please help me in another? 

I need to divide active projects by total projects. What should be the query?

Comment: Suppose query1 and query2 as 2 numbers. Then you can do any calculation. `select query1 / query2;`

Comment: The "+" working for sum, but When I replace with "/", the result showing 0.00000000000000000000.

But the result should be 0.070582038451409

Comment: Because you div integer numbers, just multiply first query to 1.0